# How to highlight text in Draftjs

Tags: reactjs, draftjs

I am facing a problem trying to highlight text that goes over a certain number of characters.

I have a function that receives `editorState` and returns it with all the necessary style changes, it's called `addOverLimitFeedback`. I am calling this function from `onChange` method:

```
...
onChange = editorState => {
  this.setState({
    editorState: this.addOverLimitFeedback(editorState)
  });
}
...
```

Apparently there is something that is causing to add twice the characters being added after the style is active.

I've got an fiddle here working so you can see the complete code, you need to type more than 10 characters to see it working (and failing): https://jsfiddle.net/newpatriks/oboj8g04/

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The jsfiddle is down could you please update it for the next users?

Answer (score 0):

https://draftjs.org/docs/advanced-topics-editorstate-race-conditions/

you may move `addOverLimitFeedback` to `handleKeyCommand`'s key release.

Comment: Link is invalid it should be https://draftjs.org/docs/advanced-topics-editorstate-race-conditions/